# iOS swift 3.0 Json parsing and alert issue

Tags: swift

I'm working on login form. I'm a fresher on iOS development.

After successful login, I want to show an alert after completion of json parsing. I've parsed `Ngoid` inside a `do while` block. Now I want to pass the value "Ngoid" to the next view controller so that  it can be used to fetch the further data.

**Main Problem:** Here is the code I have written and it gives me error to write alert it on main thread only.

As I want the "Ngoid" value for further use there, so how should I write it and what is the correct way to execute the code?

Here is the code I have written:

```
@IBAction func loginbutton(_ sender: Any) {
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.shreetechnosolution.com/funded/ngo_login.php")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

    let postString = "uname=\(textfieldusername.text!)&password=\(textfieldpassword.text!)";

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)



    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data , response , error in

        if error != nil
        {
            //let alert = UIAlertView()
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Box !", message: "Login Failed", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            return
        }

        // You can print out response object
        print("*****response = \(String(describing: response))")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data! , encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue )

        if ((responseString?.contains("")) == nil) {
            print("incorrect - try again")

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Try Again", message: "Username or Password Incorrect", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Nochmalversuchen", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in

            }


            // Add Actions
            alert.addAction(yesAction)


            // Present Alert Controller
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        else {
            print("correct good")


        }

        print("*****response data  = \(responseString!)")




        do {
            //create json object from data

            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {

                if let email = json["UserName"] as? String,
                    let password1 = json["passowrd"] as? String {

                    print ("Found User id:  called \(email)")
                }
                let msg = (json.value(forKey: "message") as! NSString!) as String
               let id = (json.value(forKey: "NgoId") as! NSString!) as String


//                    let alert : UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Alert box!", message: "\(msg!).",delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
//                    alert.show()

                self.alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Box!", message: "\(msg)", preferredStyle: .alert)
                print("the alert\(self.alert)")
                self.action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
                    let viewControllerYouWantToPresent = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pass1") as! ViewControllerngodetails

                    viewControllerYouWantToPresent.temp1 = self.id

                    self.present(viewControllerYouWantToPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }

                self.alert.addAction(self.action)

                self.present(self.alert, animated: true, completion: nil)



            }




        }catch let error {
            print(error)
        }



    }
    task.resume()

        }
```

Comment: Never put your confidential information here as base **URL** instead of this, you can write **http://www.mywebsite.com/funded/ngo_login.php**

Answer (score 3):

A pro tip:

All your UI related tasks need to be done in the main thread. Here you are presenting the alert inside a closure which executes in a background thread, thats the problem. You need to call the main queue and present alert in that block.

EDIT:

Just put your alert code in this-

For Swift 3-

Get main queue asynchronously

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    //Code Here
}
```

Get main queue synchronously

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync {
    //Code Here
}
```

Comment: This is not a Swift 3.x syntax

Answer (score 2):

Every UI update has to be on main thread:

```
@IBAction func loginbutton(_ sender: Any) {
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.shreetechnosolution.com/funded/ngo_login.php")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

    let postString = "uname=\(textfieldusername.text!)&password=\(textfieldpassword.text!)";

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)



    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data , response , error in

    if error != nil
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Box !", message: "Login Failed", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            // Present Alert Controller
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        return
    }

        // You can print out response object
        print("*****response = \(String(describing: response))")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data! , encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue )

        if ((responseString?.contains("")) == nil) {
            print("incorrect - try again")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Try Again", message: "Username or Password Incorrect", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Nochmalversuchen", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in }

                // Add Actions
                alert.addAction(yesAction)

                // Present Alert Controller
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }

        else {
            print("correct good")
        }

        print("*****response data  = \(responseString!)"

        do {
            //create json object from data

            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {

                if let email = json["UserName"] as? String,
                    let password1 = json["passowrd"] as? String {

                    print ("Found User id:  called \(email)")
                }
                let msg = (json.value(forKey: "message") as! NSString!) as String
               let id = (json.value(forKey: "NgoId") as! NSString!) as String

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Box!", message: "\(msg)", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    print("the alert\(self.alert)")
                    self.action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
                        let viewControllerYouWantToPresent = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pass1") as! ViewControllerngodetails

                        viewControllerYouWantToPresent.temp1 = self.id

                        self.present(viewControllerYouWantToPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }

                    self.alert.addAction(self.action)

                    self.present(self.alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }



            }




        }catch let error {
            print(error)
        }



    }
    task.resume()

        }
```